One ImageMagick CLI call to convert for multiple qualities
My specific goal is to convert PNG to e.g. AVIF with multiple qualities in one call to the ImageMagick (v7) command line interface. Why not multiple calls? Efficiency. The idea is to tell ImageMagick that it only needs to load an input file once, keeping it in memory, while outputting multiple files with different quality settings.
This script shows what I'm trying to do, but the last command does not have the correct syntax:
#!/bin/zsh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Input file required (.png)"
  exit 1
fi
infile=$1
basename="${infile%.*}"
mkdir -p avif
magick convert "$infile" \
-quality 50 "avif/$basename-50.avif" \
-quality 60 "avif/$basename-60.avif" \
-quality 70 "avif/$basename-70.avif"

I have both (a) searched the IM CLI documentation and (b) asked various AI tools for help. So far, no luck.

By isolating the write operations inside parentheses, ImagcMagick can write several versions of an input image from a single command. This is an example of one way to go about that...
infile=$1
basename="${infile%.*}"
mkdir -p avif

magick convert "$infile" \
   \( -clone 0 -quality 50 -write "avif/$basename-50.avif" \) \
   \( -clone 0 -quality 60 -write "avif/$basename-60.avif" \) \
   \( -clone 0 -quality 70 -write "avif/$basename-70.avif" \) \
      null:

The command reads the input image, clones it inside parentheses, sets the quality, and writes the output, then continues with the command. The same, or even different operations can be performed on additional clones and written to disk. I used "null:" at the end of the command because ImageMagick expects the command to end with an output file name, and our outputs are already written.

You can use parentheses processing for each sub-command and +write XXX to save the results and MPR: in place of -clone to save memory. Also for Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert.
#!/bin/zsh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Input file required (.png)"
  exit 1
fi
infile=$1
basename="${infile%.*}"
mkdir -p avif
magick "$infile" +write MPR:img +delete \
\( MPR:img -quality 50 +write "avif/$basename-50.avif" +delete \) \
\( MPR:img -quality 60 +write "avif/$basename-60.avif" +delete \) \
MRP:img -quality 70 "avif/$basename-70.avif"

or for symmetry (the NULL: simply says do not write any output other than the +writes and IM expects and output and we have deleted them all after the +writes))
#!/bin/zsh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Input file required (.png)"
  exit 1
fi
infile=$1
basename="${infile%.*}"
mkdir -p avif
magick "$infile" +write MPR:img +delete \
\( MPR:img -quality 50 +write "avif/$basename-50.avif" +delete \) \
\( MPR:img -quality 60 +write "avif/$basename-60.avif" +delete \) \
\( MRP:img -quality 70 +write "avif/$basename-70.avif" +delete \) \
NULL:

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#write
ADDITION
Mark Setchell has a good point. In this case there is no actual pixel processing such as -resize which would need the parentheses processing and an MPR: or -clone to work on. It only provides a setting and writes the output. So this all can be simplified as follows by just providing a +write for each output.
#!/bin/zsh
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Input file required (.png)"
  exit 1
fi
infile=$1
basename="${infile%.*}"
mkdir -p avif
magick "$infile" \
-quality 50 +write "avif/$basename-50.avif" \
-quality 60 +write "avif/$basename-60.avif" \
-quality 70 +write "avif/$basename-70.avif" \
NULL:


Hi Fred. I would have thought all the MPR and deletions are unnecessary here - surely the +write leaves the input image in its original state for subsequent wtites?

You have a good point, Mark. In this case there is no actual pixel processing such as -resize which would need the parentheses processing and an MPR:img or -clone 0 to work on. So this all can be simplified. I will modify my answer.

OK, that is done.

You already have my vote
